# Python scorekeeping

Tags: python, python-3.x, variables, variable-assignment

I've been making a scorekeeper and i can't figure out how to assign the amount of player's variables to 0. For example, if there are 3 players, then i need to assign 3 different variables the value of 0. Is this possible? If so, how? If not, how else could i do this?

```
while True:
    try:
        numPlayers = int(input("How many people are playing?"))
        if numPlayers == 0 or numPlayers == 1 or numPlayers > 23:
            print("You cannot play with less than 2 people or more than 23 
         people.")

        else:
            break

    except ValueError:
        print("Please enter an integer value.")

for numTimes in range(0, numPlayers):
    #what should i do?
```

Comment: What's stopping you from using a `list`?

Comment: Use a `list` to store scores for all players, e.g.: `scores = [0] * numPlayers`. Then `scores[0]` will be the 1st player's score, `scores[1]` 2nd player's score, ....

Comment: Thanks! i'll see if I can use a list

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use dictionary, like this:

```
players = {'player-{}'.format(num): 0 for num in range(1, num_players + 1)}
```

Maybe defaultdict from collections would fit even better for this task:

```
from collections import defaultdict

players = defaultdict(int)
players['Dirk']
# Returns 0
players['John'] += 1
print(players)
# Prints {'John': 1, 'Dirk': 0}
```

Comment: I'll also utilize dictionaries and see which one works better!